# react-admin - how can I pass a ReferenceInput id in another ReferenceInput's filter?

Tags: react-admin

I'm trying to pass exampleId from Example as a filter to ExampleTwo, how can I do this?

```
<ArrayInput source="list">
  <SimpleFormIterator>

    <ReferenceInput source="exampleId" reference="Example">
        <SelectInput optionText="name" />
    </ReferenceInput>

    <ReferenceInput source="exampleIdTwo" reference="ExampleTwo" filter={{ id: exampleId }}>
        <SelectInput optionText="name" />
    </ReferenceInput>

  </SimpleFormIterator>
</ArrayInput>
```

I'm trying to wrap in a Component using useState to get id onChange, but when I do it, this happen: resources.undefined.fields.exampleId

```
const MyComponent  = () => {
  const [exampleId, setExampleId] = useState(null);

  const handleOnChange = (e) => setExampleId(e.target.value);

  return (
          <SimpleFormIterator>

            <ReferenceInput source="exampleId" reference="Example" onChange={handleOnChange}>
                <SelectInput optionText="name" />
            </ReferenceInput>

            <ReferenceInput source="exampleIdTwo" reference="ExampleTwo" filter={{ id: exampleId }}>
                <SelectInput optionText="name" />
            </ReferenceInput>

          </SimpleFormIterator>
  )
}
```

...

```
<ArrayInput source="list">
  <MyComponent />
</ArrayInput>
```

Edit: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution...must use ReferenceInput

```
<SimpleFormIterator>
    <ReferenceInput source="exampleId" reference="Example">
        <SelectInput optionText="name" />
    </ReferenceInput>

    <FormDataConsumer >
    {
        ({ getSource, scopedFormData }) => {
        const exampleId = scopedFormData?.exampleId;
        return (
            <ReferenceInput
            source={getSource('exampleIdTwo')}
            reference="ExampleTwo"
            filter={{ id: exampleId }}
            >
                <SelectInput optionText="name" />
            </ReferenceInput>
        )
    }
    </FormDataConsumer>
</SimpleFormIterator>
```